# ASP.NET MVC 5 Filter Overrides Bug

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, filter, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

With the release of ASP.NET MVC 5 RC1, it was reported that there was a bug associated with Filter overrides feature. But ASP.NET MVC 5 released in October 17. Now I have Visual Studio 2013 with me with the updated MVC 5. It seems to be that the bug associated with the MVC 5 Filter Overrides Feature has not been fixed yet. What I need to know is get more information regarding this bug and whether they have fixed it in MVC 5.

Comment: This has been fixed in 5.1 RTM which was release 20 Jan 2014. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/20/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-1-asp-net-web-api-2-1-and-asp-net-web-pages-3-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it is a bug in current RTM

This has been fixed in the  5.1 preview.
This is the official bug and it has been fixed in 5.1 preview.
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1315

See the question on Do Filter-Overrides work in the current RC (MVC 5.0.0 RC 1) for a workaround
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/455077

You can track the items that have been fixed in
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?Release=v5.1%20Preview

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please suggest me how can I obtain MVC 5.1 preview? I can only find MVC 5 yet. Thanks.  :)

Comment: Since it is preview, I don't think it is publicly released. But it is open source so you can download from https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest                 if you clone the latest repo, you can see this particular bug has been fixed.

Comment: This has been fixed in 5.1 RTM which was release 20 Jan 2014. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/20/announcing-the-release-of-asp-net-mvc-5-1-asp-net-web-api-2-1-and-asp-net-web-pages-3-1.aspx